# Code error in hibernate @CollectionId

Tags: java, hibernate

getting error in code -

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "hilo-gen", strategy = "guid")
@CollectionId (columns ={@Column(name = "Address_ID")},type = @Type(type="long"),generator ="guid-gen" )
private Collection<AddressClass> listAddresses = new ArrayList<AddressClass>();
```

and getting this error during compilation

incompatible types: org.hibernate.mapping.Column cannot be converted to javax.persistence.Column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your file you are importing

```
org.hibernate.mapping.Column
```

Instead import

```
javax.persistence.Column
```

as described in the [`@CollectionId` javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/CollectionId.html).

If you need both `Column` classes, use the fully qualified name of the one you haven't imported to use it.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I'm sorry for bothering you because of this silly mistake.

Comment: @guptavaibhav Happens to all of us :) Good luck!